# Counter with a different score in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I'm using a `Counter` to track the amount of times a sub-string is present is a text, but I'm searching for a substring with the highest *score*. The score is defined as `len(substring) * (occurences-1)`.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

input_string = "My amazing string with all sorts of values in it. " + \
"Kaas is lekker! I want to know how many times a certain substring" + \
"of a minumum size appears in it, so I can so some value encodings" + \
". Kaas is lekker! Performance is a problem when a string become l" + \
"arger. Kaas is lekker! So many strings to replace, what string is" + \
" best?"

larger_then = 5
length = len(input_string)
subs = [input_string[i:j+1] \
  for i in range(0, length-larger_then) \
  for j in range(i+larger_then, length)]

countr = Counter()
countr.update(subs)

scores = map(lambda kv: (kv[0], len(kv[0]) * (kv[1]-1)), countr.most_common())
max_key, max_score = max(scores, key=itemgetter(1))

print("")
print("Max key is '{}' with score {}".format(max_key, max_score))
print("")
top_20 = list(countr.most_common(20))
print("Top 20 commons:", *top_20, sep="\n- ")
```

Which returns:

```
Max key is '. Kaas is lekker! ' with score 36
Top 20 commons:
- ('string', 5)
- (' strin', 4)
- (' string', 4)
- (' string ', 3)
- ('string ', 3)
- ('tring ', 3)
- ('. Kaas', 3)
- ('. Kaas ', 3)
- ('. Kaas i', 3)
- ('. Kaas is', 3)
- ('. Kaas is ', 3)
- ('. Kaas is l', 3)
- ('. Kaas is le', 3)
- ('. Kaas is lek', 3)
- ('. Kaas is lekk', 3)
- ('. Kaas is lekke', 3)
- ('. Kaas is lekker', 3)
- ('. Kaas is lekker!', 3)
- ('. Kaas is lekker! ', 3)
- (' Kaas ', 3)
```

Is there a faster way to count substrings with a different score?

Here's a link to a Repl.it with the running code: https://repl.it/@keestalkstech/CavernousKindheartedScripts

Comment: Are you trying to get some sort of compression algorithm?

Comment: Working on a string encoder.